# I want to insert a couple of sentences into an array

Tags: java

Like instance, 
in online purchasing a bill is created. I want to insert the items into the array and display it along with the rates. But I am unable to insert the items into the array. How do I do that?

Comment: What array?  What items?  What error message did you get?

Comment: I am talking about a string array. I have got a project to go about- online purchasing. How do I display the bill using array?

Comment: Show some code where you are facing issue.

Answer (score 2):

ArrayList might be better because you don't know the size of the array beforehand.

Initialize:

```
List<String> billInfo = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Process information:

```
billInfo.add(your_string_here); // this add "your_string_here" to the billInfo array
```

You can also use a for loop if you have something to loop through (for example, a Elements Jsoup node)

```
for(T t : ts){
    billInfo.add(t.someMethodThatReturnsSomeInformation);
}
```

Can you post some code so your question is more clear?